# How to store address of BST node in a queue?

Tags: c, data-structures

Warning: makes integer from pointer without a cast ,
`Bstnode` is a node of  binary tree
 `amp` is structure of queue

```
void enqueue(struct queue* amp,struct Bstnode* root){
    if(isfull(amp))
       return;
    else if(isempty(amp))
    {
       amp->rear=0;
       amp->front=0;
       amp->array[amp->rear]=root;
    }
    else
    {
        amp->rear=((amp->rear+1)%(amp->capacity));
        amp->array[amp->rear]=root;
    }

}
```

Is this error that I am getting is due to `amp->array[amp->rear]=root;`
because root is a pointer
If then what will be the way if I want to store the address of `struct Bstnode`
that is the address of nodes of BST in a queue.
Please give a pointer to my error

Comment: Just define `array[]` as an array of pointers to `struct Bstnode` instead of array ot integers.

Comment: Can you write the definition of `struct queue` , or at least of `array` ? Is `array` a pointer or an array? The answer depends on that. When you do that, please add my name to a comment, so that I get notified about the update.